# FFMPEG, producing stream, wish to write to disk while streaming, segmenting

Tags: ffmpeg, raspbian, h.264, rtsp

)

I have fought the long battle of getting somehow familiar with this wonderful beast of a thing, FFMPEG. I have coped with several things, learned that I will never get old enough to at least master 1% of it, but everything I need so far works "a charm"...

...except one thing:

Streaming an RTSP stream works fine, but I can't make the

```
-f tee
```

thing work in order to simultaneously stream AND write segmented files to disk. Either one works, using -f tee makes the whole thing fail and I can't find a solution for the error message...

I let ffmpeg send its stream to "rtsp-simple-server", which I consider a good solution so far. At the same time I wish to write to disk. Command line:

````
ffmpeg -threads 3 -fflags +igndts -vsync 1 -stats -re -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1286x972 -fflags +genpts -i /dev/video0 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -c:v h264_omx -copytb 1 -b:v 500K -maxrate 500K -bufsize 500K -map 0:v -f tee "[f=segment:segment_time=60:segment_format=mp4]capture-%03d.mp4|[f=rtsp]rtsp://localhost:$RTSP_PORT/$RTSP_PATH"
```
$RTSP_PORT=8554, $RTSP_PATH=cam. I expected a regular stream and some files in the current directory, but all I got was:
```
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 10461.790201, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1286x972, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 2000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_omx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_omx @ 0x5dbab0] Using OMX.broadcom.video_encode
[segment @ 0x6313b0] Opening 'capture-000.mp4' for writing
2023/01/13 00:43:17 INF [RTSP] [conn [::1]:41996] opened
2023/01/13 00:43:17 INF [RTSP] [session 8091f947] created by [::1]:41996
2023/01/13 00:43:17 INF [RTSP] [session 8091f947] is publishing to path 'cam', with UDP, 1 track (H264)
Output #0, tee, to '[f=segment:segment_time=60:segment_format=mp4]capture-%03d.mp4|[f=rtsp]rtsp://localhost:8554/cam':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_omx), yuv420p, 1286x972, q=2-31, 500 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 h264_omx
[tee @ 0x5da9b0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
````

As you can see, I am using a raspbian installation on a Pi4 with the h264_omx encoder. I am pretty sure, there's a problem with this encoder, but for some reason I can't find out, what it is as I couldn't even find docs about it.

Problem is that regular encoders can't keep up performance wise as the _omx utilizes the Raspi's little graphic gadget and the others don't: CPU is unable to keep up with what I would see in terms of encoding and file size.

So my question: Is there any way to keep the h264_omx encoder while a) streaming and b) writing segmented files to disk? I can see it's something along the timestamps but all flags I came by had no effect :-(

Please help my little ARM toy to fulfill its purpose and end my pain :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found out that h264_omx won't work using the "tee" approach to simultaneously stream and save the stream to disk.

Instead of re-encoding an h.264 stream, provided by the camera, just to change bitrate, I set up the camera via v4l2 control to do so. Transport inside ffmpeg is now basically c:v copy, which keeps load to a minimum.

So: Bitrate limit is checked, profile is checked, rest is disposed, load stays safe...

Still: Sad, that h264_omx doesn't receive enough love with all the raspis being used for camera and streaming applications :-(